# Javascript regex with below validation rules

Tags: javascript, regex

Allowable characters:

1. uppercase A to Z
2. lowercase a to z
3. hyphen
4. apostrophe
5. single quote
6. space
7. full stop
8. numerals 0 to 9

validations:

- Must contain alphabetic characters
- Cannot have consecutive non alpha characters except for full stop followed by a space OR  apostrophe can be followed by a space
- Cannot have non-alphabetic characters at the start (except for apostrophe)
- Can end with a full stop

I have a regex with the below validation. Use this as reference

```
/^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9`'. -]+$)(?!.*[0-9'` -]{2})[a-zA-Z'][^\r\n.]*(?:\.[ a-z][^\r\n.]*)*$/;
```

Need to add the below validations to the above regex

1. Can end with a full stop
2. An apostrophe can be followed by a space.

Examples Valid

1. 'Andy
2. Andy.
3. Andy' De'Wall
4. Andy. DeWa2e
5. A2dy'

Examples Invalid

1. 2Andy
2. A2'ndy.
3. Andy'-Wall
4. Andy. DeWa23
5. A24dy'

Comment: add sample valid and invalid inputs

Comment: As per the comment above, I'd highly suggest adding samples of the valid and invalid inputs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- assert not 2 consecutive digits `.` `'` or `-`
- assert not a digit or hyphen or space followed by a space
- assert at least a char A-Z a-z
- start the match with either `'` or a char A-Z a-z

For example

```
^(?!.*[0-9.'-]{2})(?!.*[0-9 -] )(?=[^A-Za-z\n]*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z'][A-Za-z0-9.' -]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B3mkbT/1)

Comment: The Regex above fails the validation **Andy.** which should be valid.

Comment: @rebel If you click on the regex demo link, you will see that it matches **Andy.**